# The system cannot find the file specified in Rmarkdown

Tags: r

I am doing my current project in RStudio Desktop. I am doing RMarkdown to later transfer. I am having some trouble getting an error of the system cannot find the file specified RMarkdown. At first, it says that the combined_databike was not found, but I literally did it in the same file already also you can see in the upper right all of the data frames which mention "combined_databike." This being said when I am trying to hit knit it gives me the error. Now the error says is at the tripdata_202006, which I cannot understand because I imported every file from tripdata_202006 to tripdata_202105 using the "import dataset."

[image]
I want to understand why is not working and how I bring a solution.

Comment: Look at `here` or some other "environment" helper. Otherwise, use `listfiles` or `ls` to check if the file actually is in the target path.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the file you want to read is not in the folder where your project or in this case your rmarkdown file is.

As you can see in the file list of your console, in your directory you have 4 files, and you don't have the folder `"Bike data"` where the file `202006-divvy-tripdata.csv` is located, according to the path that is in line 83 of your code.

Maybe to solve that, I think you have two options, the first one is to write the whole path to the folder location and then to the file. And the second option is to move the folder "Bike data" with the files you have in it, where your rmarkdown file is located.

Answer (score -1):

Please ensure to include the
library(tidyverse)
command at the top of your scripts immediately you open the rmarkdown open and close brace

```
{r}
```